# How to extend template in odoo 9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm using odoo 9 , I want to extend a template.
See my code

```
 <templates id="olims.cust_template" xml:space="preserve">
     <t t-extend="web.UserMenu.about">
         <t t-jquery=".container-fluid" t-operation="replace">
             <div class="row">
        -----my code here-----
            </div>

         </t>
     </t>
</templates>
```

But there is no effect in About Menu, What's wrong with the code, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

**1 -**  Use `<t t-extend="UserMenu.about">` to extend the template.
**2 -**  Add `web` to `depends` in the manifest (`__openerp__.py`).
**3 -**  Add `'qweb': ["static/src/xml/*.xml"],` to the manifest.

> > Template inheritance is performed via the t-extend directive which takes the name of the template to alter as parameter.

You can find more at [QWEB](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/qweb.html).

Comment: Did you try to remove `.web`. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes,I removed .web but still not working. I didn't find the solution yet

Comment: Can you describe the whole steps, you followed to create the template?